# React native & firebase forgot password

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a forgot password feature.
I am getting the success message and everything seems to be working besides me actually getting the email?
Code below:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

const forgotPassword = () => {
    auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(() => {
        navigation.navigate('ResetSuccess');
    }).catch(error => alert(error.message));
}
```

then the trigger

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={forgotPassword}>
   <Text style={styles.forgotPasswordButton}>Reset Password</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: did you check spam?

Comment: Yep, nothing at all